# How can I query ObservableCollection List

Tags: c#, linq, uwp

I have a property on my VM, and it is bounded to ListView

```
    private FindCollection _searchMatches;
    public FindCollection SearchMatches {
        get { return _searchMatches; }
        set { this.Set(ref _searchMatches, value); }
    }
```

my "FindCollection" class inherited ObserveCollection:

```
FindCollection : ObservableCollection<MyClass>
```

On My FindCollection I have a LoadItems Task, which is called every time navigated to my view:

```
async Task<IList<MyClass>> LoadItems()

var stocks = _response.products?
                    .Select(s => new MyClass(PLService.DtoToModel(s)))
                    .ToList();
            var items = stocks.GroupBy(p => p.productModel.Description)
                                    .Select(p => p.First())
                                    .ToList();
            return items;
```

So SearchMatches now have items
When user search for string , I want to sort the List Items , where description is equal to searchterm
How to query it to `SearchMatches.Where(s.description == searchterm)` to my VM;

**UPDATE:** SearchMatches contains {MyClass}, and MyClass{eachproduct}

Thanks,
NicoTing

Comment: Did you tried? It should work, remember to add directive `using System.Linq`

Comment: What error do you get when you try to do it?

Comment: Doing `SearchMatches.Where(s => s.description == "test")` is the correct way. Have you tried that?

Comment: Already tried that , but Cannot implicity convert type 'IEnumerable<MyClass>' to 'FindCollection'

Comment: Are you trying assign result of query to new instance of `FindCollection`? FindCollection result = SearchMatches.Where(s => s.description == "test");` ? If so then you need explicitly convert it to correct type. You can create a constructor which takes `IEnumerable<T>` as parameter

Comment: @Fabio ok I will try that.

Comment: @Fabio uhhm my FindCollection property is in my VM, and I want to sort it out by query. can you please give an example code

Comment: Please update question with code you have tried and exception message you got on which line. Without this information all comments/answers is just guessing.

Comment: @Fabio Ive updated the question , is it clear for you now?

Comment: @NicoTing If [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45276179/7331395) answer works then consider Mark as Answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var query  = SearchMatches.Where(s => s.Description.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm.ToLower()));
        FindCollection collection = new FindCollection();
        foreach (var r in query )
        {
            collection.Add(r);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [AdvancedCollectionView](http://www.uwpcommunitytoolkit.com/en/master/helpers/AdvancedCollectionView/) from UWPCommunityToolkit. It will make your work very simple.

To use `AdvancedCollectionView` you should install [Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI/) nuget package.

Here is the syndax:

```
var acv = new AdvancedCollectionView(oc);  //oc is your ObservableCollection
acv.Filter = s => s.Description.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm.ToLower());
YourListView.ItemsSource = acv;
```

For more info: [AdvancedCollectionView](http://www.uwpcommunitytoolkit.com/en/master/helpers/AdvancedCollectionView/)

Comment: Thanks for the respond , but this is what I did :
IEnumerable<MyClass> query = SearchMatches.Where(s => s.Description.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm.ToLower()));


i just need to assign SearchMatches = query;

Comment: @NicoTing So you solved your issue. Then post it as the answer. But my recommendation is to use [AdvancedCollectionView](http://www.uwpcommunitytoolkit.com/en/master/helpers/AdvancedCollectionView/) because it has all the feature you need like sorting, filtering, NotificationDeferrer.

Comment: Iam not done yet , I still need to set "SearchMatches" to "query" , cause I need the list to be updated too. Ok i will give a try on AdvancedCollectionView , but I dont know yet , how to import that project to my app, may  I know how?

Comment: I have updated my answer. To update the list you need to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.INotifyPropertyChanged). But if you use `AdvancedCollectionView` you don't want to implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: I installed Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp, but still cant call "AdvancedCollectionView" , what am I missing? all potential fix is just generate class. I clean , Rebuil my solution

Thanks

Comment: @NicoTing Sorry you should install Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI

Comment: so okay , install toolkit uwp ui instead of toolkit uwp? right?

Comment: @NicoTing Yes. It was a mistake in ToolKit Documentation

Comment: funny , but still cant call AdvanceCollectionView

Comment: @NicoTing Did you use `using Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI;`

Comment: its okay now , I added the dependencies on my VM , cause Im calling that on my VM

Comment: @NicoTing What happened?

Comment: sorry I didnt finish solving my problem yesterday , I cant use this:
var acv = new AdvancedCollectionView(SearchMatches);
//on my s.(no Description)
acv.Filter = s => s.Description.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm.ToLower());
Btw SearchMatches is bounded to my listview , so I need to assign the result to my SearchMatches